# javascript: take first args from String array and let the rest join again

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got a String array, where I just need the first argument. The rest needs to be a string again. As an example, i use discord.js, and I work on a /kick command, so the usermention will be argument 1 and the rest will be the reason. But How could the array "Arguments" create a whole string without using the very first index? At the moment I just got this:

```
//The given arguments in the command get separated
var Arguments = message.content.split(" ");

//testing purpose, if the first index really is the mentioned user
message.channel.send("Username: " + Arguments[1]);

//joining the reasons together to a whole string
var reason = Arguments.join(/*This is the part where I don't know how to tell the array to ignore the first index*/);
```

Comment: please add an example of the string and the result as well.

Comment: @MushMello, if you don't care about changing Arguments, you can just [shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) to remove the first element.

Comment: `Arguments.slice(1).join(' ')`

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning arguments to an array in the beginning:

```
var args = message.content.split(" ");
```

then before joining them you can remove the first element from the `args`:

```
args.shift();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use shift and join to do the trick

```js
var a=["fd","fdd","fsdsd"]
console.log(a.shift())  //first element
console.log(a.join(",")); //rest in a string form
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ES6 [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
const Arguments = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Peach', 'Pear'];
    
const [first, ...remaining] = Arguments;
    
console.log(first) // Apple
    
const joinedRemaining = remaining.join(', ');
    
console.log(joinedRemaining); // Banana, Peach, Pear
```

Notice that in:

```
const [first, ...remaining] = Arguments;
```

`first` is the first value and `remaining` is the *array* with all the values, except the first

Answer (score 0):

You can use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```js
let str = "hello world how are you";
let splitStr = str.split(' ');
let arg = splitStr[0];
let rest = splitStr.slice(1).join(' ')
console.log(arg,'\n',rest)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use desctructuring and the spread syntax to get the tail of the array:

```js
const arguments = ['jack', 'john', 'sylvia', 'eddy'];
const [_, ...rest] = arguments;
const argString = rest.join(' ');
console.log(argString);
```